# Key-binding to open a terminal running python in ratpoison

Tags: shell, python, ratpoison

In my .ratpoisonrc file I'm failing to write a key-binding to open a terminal running python.  I'm running a minimal Debian setup on which I basically just run emacs.  Sometimes I want to just get a python shell and I'm not sure how to set up the key binding to get that right.

```
bind p exec ???? python
```

Comment: Try this as command: `xterm -e python`

Comment: I've tried xterm and it doesn't do it.  It was what I thought it should be, but it's not working.  It gives me `/bin/sh -c "xterm -e  python" finnished (127)` and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bind p exec x-terminal-emulator --title python -e /usr/bin/python
```

(but I'd highly recommend using ipython as an interactive python)

If x-terminal-emulator isn't using your current favorite terminal emulator (xterm vs rxvt vg gnome-terminal, etc) then run `update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`