# How do I bind the Python interpeter to a key?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently I open the interpreter with a keybinding pointing to
`gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --full-screen` then type `python`

I want to open it directly.

I've tried:

`gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --full-screen && python`

`/usr/bin/./python`

...as well as the advice in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31827/key-binding-to-open-a-terminal-running-python-in-ratpoison):

`bind '<Super>8' exec x-terminal-emulator --title python -e /usr/bin/python`

Note  that I'd also like to preserve `--hide-menubar --full-screen`

Thanks

Comment: Try the -e python instead of && python to get gnome-terminal to run python instead of bash, see http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal

Comment: Worked. Thanks! Want to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the -e python instead of && python to get gnome-terminal to run python instead of bash, see [its man page](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/gnome_terminal)